# How to copy file and rename depending on subfolder

Tags: gradle, copy, rename

I am trying to copy a file in gradle and rename it at the same time, where the new name of the file should be dependent of the name of the subfolder it was in.

My file structure looks like this for example:

```
├── apk
│   └── app-envTest-normalBuild-release.apk
├── logs
│   └── manifest-merger-envTest-normalBuild-release-report.txt
└── mapping
    └── envTestNormalBuild
        └── release
            ├── dump.txt
            ├── mapping.txt
            ├── seeds.txt
            └── usage.txt
```

I'd like to copy the `mapping.txt` and rename it. The new name should be `mapping-envTestNormalBuild.txt` - i.e. should include the name of the subdirectory it was released in.

**Can someone tell me if/how this is possible using the gradle copy+rename feature?**

I have seen that the [reverse is possible](http://mrhaki.blogspot.ch/2010/10/gradle-goodness-renaming-files-while.html), i.e. copying a file like `foo-bar.txt` to a directory/path `foo/bar.txt` and similar.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try e.g.:

```
task clean {
  doLast {
    project.file('dest').deleteDir()
  }
}

task cp(type: Copy) {
  dependsOn clean
  from 'mapping/envTestNormalBuild/release'
  into 'dest'
  include 'mapping.txt'
  eachFile { fcp ->
      fcp.name = "$fcp.file.parentFile.parentFile.name-$fcp.name"
  }
}
```

A demo can be found [here](https://github.com/Opalo/stackoverflow/tree/master/42780608).

Comment: Maybe one question still: this will create the file including the sub-directories it's found in... any way I can skip these directories, i.e. put the renamed file in the actual path I specify in `toPath`?

Comment: @fgysin, I guess it may be configured via [FileCopyDetails](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/file/FileCopyDetails.html). You just need to experiment a bit ;)

Comment: Was able to solve it using `from ... .include("...").files`. The `files` part makes sure that we don't copy any directories.